# Composer error: "Could not open input file: /usr/bin/composer.phar"

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have successfully run composer for Laravel projects in the past, but this time it doesn't want to work. None of the existing threads on StackOverflow had any useful solutions for me.

I re-installed composer, and it lives at Users/becky. I tried moving it to /usr/bin/, since that seems to be where CL thinks it lives, but then I get this message: "No such file or directory"

Okay! I'm stumped! Any takers?

Comment: What command are you using to invoke composer? just 'composer' or 'composer.phar'? Are you using a vagrant machine or any virtual machine that should be provisioned to run composer?

Answer (score 1):

TYPO:

```
   mv /Users/becky/composer.phar /usr/loca/bin/composer.phar
```

SHOULD BE:

```
   mv /Users/becky/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the name of your user directory, I'm guessing you're on OS X. OS X, since El Capitan, does not allow access to `/usr/bin`. Instead, install composer in `/usr/local/bin`. That directory is in your path by default and you have access to it.

To move it from your directory, use:

```
mv /Users/becky/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
```

Then create an alias:

```
alias composer="/usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
```